# Eliminating Duplicates in a CSV with True and False Values

Tags: r, csv, merge

I have a CSV with over 173 columns (characters and logical values) and 100000 rows. Among the data there are duplicate values but they have different information in the columns. I want to merge the data to eliminate the duplicates using the last name as Key for identification

e.g.  Input

```
    last name   gender       completed         received         state
    Smith       male          FALSE            FALSE             IA
    Jones       female        TRUE             FALSE             DC 
    Simmons                   TRUE             TRUE  
    Simmons     male          FALSE            TRUE              CA
    Smith       male          TRUE             TRUE
```

e.g.  Output

```
    last name   gender       completed         received         state
    Smith       male          TRUE             TRUE              IA
    Jones       female        TRUE             FALSE             DC 
    Simmons     male          TRUE             TRUE              CA
```

How can I do this?

Comment: The fields for records marked completed = FALSE may conflict with the same field in the one marked completed = TRUE - you do not mention which has precedence. You also do not state whether or not fields with values when completed = FALSE are to be carried over if the same field has no value when completed = TRUE. Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks Stewart.  It's important to always maintain TRUE.  Regardless if the record says FALSE in the second instance.

Answer (score 0):

Creation of your dataset

```
last_name<-c("Smith","Jones","Simmons","Simmons","Smith")
gender<-c("male","female",NA,"male","male")         
completed<-c(FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE)
received<-c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE)
state<-c("IA","DC",NA,"CA",NA)
dataset<-as.data.frame(cbind(last_name, gender, completed, received, state))
```

Splitting the dataset using variable "completed"

```
dataset_T<-dataset[dataset$completed==T,]
dataset_F<-dataset[dataset$completed==F,]
```

Identify duplicated values and their position (variable "pos") using "last_name"

```
last_name_dup<- dataset_F$last_name %in%  dataset_T$last_name
library (fastmatch) #function fmatch
pos<-fmatch(dataset_T$last_name,dataset_F$last_name)
```

Merge "state" information

```
state_NA<-is.na(dataset_T$state)
dataset_T[state_NA,"state"]<- dataset_F[pos[state_NA],"state"]
```

Merge "gender" information

```
gender_NA<-is.na(dataset_T$gender)
dataset_T[gender_NA,"gender"]<- dataset_F[pos[gender_NA],"gender"]
```

Bind dataset with completed=T and F

```
dataset_output<-rbind(dataset_T,dataset_F[!last_name_dup,])
```

The result:

```
  last_name gender completed received state
2     Jones female      TRUE    FALSE    DC
3   Simmons   male      TRUE     TRUE    CA
5     Smith   male      TRUE     TRUE    IA
```